# can't edit the flutter plugin native android code

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I have a big problem , I want to create a flutter plugin , when I open example/android folder in android studio and gradle finishes sync ,and I select android category in the top left side in android studio , then I can't find the plugin native code that I want to edit , and if I open the base android folder i.e : that is in root project not in example folder , then I see these red lines errors in importing flutter libs

```
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.FlutterPlugin
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result
```

so how to edit the native android plugin code and without the red error lines ?

Answer (score 0):

Right, you have to open example/android folder
But before that, run `flutter pub get` in example folder, relaunch Android Studio and your plugin with native code will appear